# How to merge the cells in openoffice?

Tags: openoffice.org

How to merge two columns in open office? For example i have the following datas in cloumns as follows.

A1  10    |     B1 10
A2  11    |     B2 20
A3  12    |     B3 30
A4  13    |     B4 40

Is it possible to merge these two columns into one. So that i should get the output like you see below,

A1 1010
A2 1120
A3 1230
A4 1340

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either use a formula in column C like `=CONCATENATE(A1,B1)` -- copy the resulting column and use `edit > paste special` to paste "numbers" and not "formulas" if you want to lock in results.

Or, you can select each pair of side by side cells (A1, B1) and merge them (`format > merge cells...`). You'll see a dialog ("Should the contents of hidden cells be merged into the first cell?") -- answer yes.  If you just have four rows, that won't take long. If you've got quite a few rows, the formula option will be more efficient.

Comment: Nice one, Amanda!

Comment: Note: someone suggested that you need to use `=CONCATENATE(A1;B1)` (with a `;` semicolon instead of a `,` comma). If the above is returning errors, try switching your delimiter. I have vague recollections of getting in trouble with commas vs. semicolons switching between Calc and Excel a decade ago, but haven't run into that issue recently.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a formula in column C like `=CONCATENATE(A1;B1)` -- copy the resulting column and use edit > paste special to paste "numbers" and not "formulas" if you want to lock in results.